# Compiling with MinGW without administrator privileges or access to the command line

Tags: c, windows, windows-xp, mingw, system-administration

I have installed DevC++ at school so I can compile C apps but every time I try to compile I get an error reading the command prompt is disabled by the sysadmin.

How can I compile anyway?

Compiler is MinGW.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The system administrator has disabled the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the person responsible for the school's computers and tell him/her that you want to learn programming and thus require access to a command prompt. Having a CLI available is always a good thing. And frankly: Disabling access to the command line? WTF?! That's no security at all.

Comment: Good idea, I'll ask my teacher next lesson. He has access to the sysadmin's account.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem at my school. I solved it using a little program that reads text from the console and used it as argument to system() (in C++). It worked well for me, although the current working directory etc isn't saved between the commands, but that can be solved using `&&` to concatenate the commands and executing them at once. Just in case your teacher won't give you access to the cmd...

Comment: Add a GUI to it, which allows you to work interactively and you've got yourself a simple enough shell. Your very answer is, why I mentioned in my answer that disabling the command prompt on a machine, where people are supposed to develop programs (for their education) is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like pretty tight restrictions. I don't know that there are good ways around it without just re-enabling command prompt. Are you sure it's compiling that needs a command prompt? I'd think it'd be running the app that needs it, if anything.

However, before you try anything like that, it'd be a pretty good idea to try installing Code::Blocks and using that instead. C::B is much more modern than DevC++ and might not require this privilege for just compiling and running apps that don't need a console window. As a bonus, I'm pretty sure C::B is compatible with DevC++ project files and devpaks.

As an additional solution, if you're dealing with a Windows XP system, most of the time a few simple registry modifications can re-enable these things. Even if regedit is disabled, you can still edit the registry using the APIs directly; there might be tools for this across the internet.

Comment: For the last solution, I did a quick Google search and came up with this, which looks pretty useful: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/disablecmd.htm - it regards malicious software, but it should work just as well for intentional restrictions.

Comment: Modifying the system settings at school may result in a ban and alot of punisment :)

Comment: @Radek S: While that is true, the possibility is very insignificant. If it were significant, the school would invest more into securing the software in the first place. Most schools are completely oblivious to actual threats (which is why USB drive viruses flourish in schools.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following workaround: create a batch file (with `.bat` extension) with contents:

```
set path=%path%;c:\myfolder\mingw\bin
gcc hello.c >out.txt
start out.txt
```

Using command prompt is not very comfortable as you usually want to set some environment variables before launching the compiler. When you have a batch file you just double click on it. You may also add `pause` at the end.